# NewRelic Agent Runtime Error -- logs look clean

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, analytics, newrelic

I tried starting up NewRelic with my server, I followed the install instructions however, whenever I run the validate, the website gives me the following response back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/newrelic-1.3.0.289/newrelic/api/error_trace.py", line 69, in __call__ return self._nr_next_object(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/newrelic-1.3.0.289/newrelic/api/function_trace.py", line 86, in __call__ return self._nr_next_object(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/newrelic-1.3.0.289/newrelic/admin.py", line 165, in _function3 raise RuntimeError('error') 
RuntimeError: error
```

I checked the logs and however the logs seem clean.  I tried installing a few different ways. I also tried base configs and regular configs.  The Server Monitoring service works, however the application service doesn't.

Stacktrace from Newrelic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSoWv.jpg

The Latest Logfile: http://pastebin.com/cwfaMcJv

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the config validation is to test the connection and test that data, including sample transaction traces and errors can be reported. So the fact that it reported some errors was perfectly normal.